# I am trying to inlcude an apostrophe in a string so I can ignore it as punctuation in a text file

Tags: python, string, if-statement, escaping, jupyter

So I am creating a string as follows;

```
basic_punc = ' \n.,/?!:;()[]{}-~&\"\'—'
```

I am trying to use the escape character to include the apostrophe in my string, so that in my code:

```
if (not char.isalnum()) & (not char in basic_punc):
# Do the rest of my function here....
```

Where char is the character that I am looking at. However, my code does not seem to recognize the apostrophe as belonging to my basic_punc. I have tried enclosing the string in double quotes, removing the escape character, yet my function continues to see the apostrophe as not a part of the string that I created. What can I do? I am using jupyter notebook if that is relevant at all.

Update: so I have been printing out the dictionary that I have been using, and here is the rest of my function:

```
 if (not char.isalnum()) & (not char in basic_punc):
            # Look up if I have seen this character before!
            print(hidden)
            print(char)
            if not char in hidden: 
                hidden[char] = index
                index += 1 
                print("'" in hidden)

            # Find the second hidden character
            end = line.find(char, i+1)
            word = line[i+1:end]
            sentences[hidden.get(char)].append(word)
            line = line[end+1:]
            i = end
```

My output for printing hidden is :
{'<': 0, '$': 1, '#': 2, '’': 3}. It says that the apostrophe is not in my dictionary, but then what is this character?

Comment: Your string is fine, something else is going on.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have done some other mistakes in your program, cause:

```
>>basic_punc = ' \n.,/?!:;()[]{}-~&\"\'—'
>>'\'' in basic_punc
True
>>"'" in basic_punc
True
```